# Can't access host serial port on VirtualBox Winxp

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port

My host is ubuntu 11.04.
The guest is WinXP VirtualBox is 4.0.10

The serial port works well with putty in ubuntu.

I setup as: COM1/4/0x3F8/Host Device/
Port Path: /dev/ttyS0

Then I close putty, to make serial port is free. After windows XP and Device Manager started, I see there is a LPT1 instead of COM1 under "Ports(COM & LPT)"

I followed the procedure in this topic( [How to access serial ubuntu host serial port on VirtualBox guest OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16586/how-to-access-serial-ubuntu-host-serial-port-on-virtualbox-guest-os/102038#102038) ), but the issue keeps not resolved.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You may suffer from a bug in earlier versions of virtual box:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7411

This issue was fixed from Virtual Box release 4.1.0.

You may succed by simply [upgrading to the most recent version](https://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940) (at present 4.1.8).

Comment: Upgrading to 4.1.8 fixed my issue. Thank you!